# PHP get content in <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Tags: php

Im trying to get the content what is is the javascript script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> [CONTENT HERE] </script>
```

currently i have something like this:

```
$start = preg_quote('<script type="text/javascript">', '/');
$end = preg_quote('</script>', '/');

preg_match('/ '.$start. '(.*?)' .$end.' /', $test, $matches);
```

But when i vardump it, its empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
$test = '<script type="text/javascript"> [CONTENT HERE] </script>';
$start = preg_quote('<script type="text/javascript">', '/');
$end = preg_quote('</script>', '/');

preg_match("/$start(.*?)$end/", $test, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '<script type="text/javascript"> [CONTENT HERE] </script>' (length=56)
  1 => string ' [CONTENT HERE] ' (length=16)
```

The problem is actually the spaces after and before `/` in the `preg_match`

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression requires there to be a space before the script start tag:

> ```
> '/ '
> ```

The code works fine when I add that space to the data:

```
<?php
$test = ' <script type="text/javascript"> [CONTENT HERE] </script> ';
$matches = [];

$start = preg_quote('<script type="text/javascript">', '/');
$end = preg_quote('</script>', '/');

preg_match('/ '.$start. '(.*?)' .$end.' /', $test, $matches);

print_r($matches);
?>
```

Changing `'/ '` to `'/'` also works.

… but that said, you should [avoid regular expressions when processing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and [use a real parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use `strip_tags` instead...

```
$txt='<script type="text/javascript"> [CONTENT HERE] </script>';
echo strip_tags($txt);
```

Outputs

```
 [CONTENT HERE]
```